# Javascript - Filtrar array de objetos

Tags: javascript

E tenho um array de objetos em javascript:

```
var array = 
[
    {
        conta_id : "7",
        marcar : 1,
        pag_data_emissao : "04/08/2015",
        pag_debito_credito : "D",
        pag_historico : "CHEQUE 331107  VENDA S",
        pag_id : "47782",
        pag_utilizado :"VENDA S",
        pag_valor : "7.000,00"
    },
    {
        conta_id : "7",
        marcar : 0,
        pag_data_emissao : "07/08/2015",
        pag_debito_credito : "D",
        pag_historico : "DEPOSITO 3117  VENDA X",
        pag_id : "47783",
        pag_utilizado :"VENDA X",
        pag_valor : "640,63"
    }
];
```

gostaria de filtrar o array com o metodo .filter() onde me retornasse todos os objetos que tenham o atributo marcar == 1, mas só achei literatura e inglês então não consegui entender direito como ficaria.

```
var a = array.filter(function(obj){ obj.marcar==1; });
```

Com o código acima ele não dá erro mas também não me trás nada.

Comment: faltou o return na função.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

o único problema é que a funćão que você usa tem que retornar o valor. Mude seu código para:

```
var filtrado = array.filter(function(obj) { return obj.marcar == 1; });
```

Que vai funcionar.

Comment: opa obrigado funcionou mesmo! :)

Comment: Disponha! Só lembre de marcar a resposta como correta ;)

Comment: sim, tenho que aguardar +10min... :( mas assim que liberar eu marcarei

Comment: Acho que essa foi a minha respota mais rápida! :D

Comment: Desculpe eu tinha esquecido de aceitar essa resposta