# Como pesquisar numa collection de JSON um determinado registro com Angular 2x?

Tags: angular

Tenho um JSON neste formato:

```
[
    {
        "agencia": "2342342",
        "digito_agencia": "2342",
        "numero_conta": "234234",
        "digito_conta": "23423",
        "_id": "5bff1a63a617f53414766c27",
        "createdAt": "2018-11-28T22:44:51.567Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-28T22:44:51.574Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "bancos": {
            "nome_banco": "001 - BANCO DO BRASIL S/A",
            "_id": "5bf2eb4bc3910712f4604847",
            "id": "5bf2eb4bc3910712f4604847",
            "updatedAt": "2018-11-28T22:42:11.276Z",
            "contasJogador": "5bff0c013efde3235465a39f",
            "nome_do_banco": "5bff0dc1d40d01202418df4b",
            "contasjogador": [
                "5bff18eed8d38e1e7c99e83a"
            ]
        },
        "id": "5bff1a63a617f53414766c27",
        "jogador": {
            "nome": "Ramos Janones",
            "email": "ramos@ramosdainformatica.com.br",
            "cpf": "03472925698",
            "celular": "34996320391",
            "telefone": "",
            "cep": "38300070",
            "endereco": "DEZESSEIS",
            "cidade": "Ituiutaba",
            "estado": "Minas Gerais",
            "bairro": "",
            "complemento": "",
            "usuario": "ramos",
            "senha": "teste123",
            "idppoker": "",
            "nickppocker": "ramosinfo",
            "numero": "",
            "_id": "5bf18c512af2e61ab879d2f7",
            "createdAt": "2018-11-18T15:59:13.735Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-11-26T15:41:00.806Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "5bf18c512af2e61ab879d2f7",
            "foto": null,
            "contasJogadors": null
        },
        "tipocontas": {
            "tipo_conta": "Conta Poupança",
            "_id": "5bff19328ff184285c7131df",
            "createdAt": "2018-11-28T22:39:46.676Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-11-28T22:42:11.275Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "5bff19328ff184285c7131df",
            "contasjogador": [
                "5bff18eed8d38e1e7c99e83a"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Preciso pegar esses dados quando o id do `"jogador"` for igual ao passado, neste caso do JSON a cima seria `"id": "5bff19328ff184285c7131df"`.

Meu service tenho:

```
query(): Observable<any> {
  const id = localStorage.getItem('ref');
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, ${id});
}
```

Onde `localStorage.getItem('ref')` é o id do jogador armazenado no `localStorage`.

Como faço para pegar apenas pelo id do `"jogador"` como filtro neste array para jogar no `*ngFor` da View?

Comment: Aqui no site existem varias perguntas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81713 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/330819 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185806 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292455

Comment: Para mais, basta acessar [essa pesquisa no Google](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=javascript+filtrar+array+site:pt.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Minha pergunta conseguiu te ajudar? Caso não me fale mais como posso ajuda-lo :D

Answer (score 1):

Opa, tudo bem?

Você pode usar o `filter`, ele retorna o item do Array que satisfaz uma condição, você pode ver mais [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

Segue a forma que fiz

```js
const jogadores = [
  {
    id: '1',
    jogador: {
      nome: 'Eduardo',
      email: 'eduardo@eduardo.com'
    }
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    jogador: {
      nome: 'Jose',
      email: 'jose@jose.com'
    }
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    jogador: {
      nome: 'Ribeiro',
      email: 'ribeiro@ribeiro.com'
    }
  }
]

const filtraJogadores = (id, jogadores) => {
  return jogadores.filter(jogador => jogador.id === id)
}

let jogadorFiltrado = filtraJogadores('1', jogadores)

console.log(jogadorFiltrado)
```

Claro, o meu exemplo está bem mais simples que o seu, mas a lógica é essa, porém como você está usando o padrão `Observable`, você terá de usar o `subscribe`, algo do tipo;

```
this.query()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.jogador = this.filtraJogadores(ID_A_SER_FILTRADO, data)
  }, error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

Se ficou alguma dúvida deixa seu comentário aqui abaixo, se for preciso eu edito e faço uma resposta mais completa.